# generalization of 8 pieces on the diagonals of a chess board

Tags: combinatorics

Arising from a variant of the $8$-queens-problem I am asking myself the following, more general question:
We distribute $n_1 + \ldots + n_m$ pairwise different balls into $m$ baskets with $n_1 , \ldots , n_m \in \mathbb N$ balls each. What is the number of possible outcomes if we draw $k < m$ different baskets and then draw one ball each? If $n_1 = \ldots = n_k$ the answer would trivially be $\binom m k \cdot n_1^k$ but that each basket has a different number of balls is confusing me.
I originally thought of this problem by thinking about distributing $8$ chess pieces on the diagonals from top-left to bottom-right without having two or more pieces on one diagonal. While it is easy to come up with some counting patterns to implement, I unfortunately couldn't come up with a general formula.

Comment: There is a generating function answer: expand $(1+n_1x)(1+n_2x)\cdots(1+n_m x)$ and find the coefficient of $x^k$.  In a sense this could take $O(km)$ time and use $O(k)$ memory to store the necessary calculations

Comment: Interesting, thank you for your comment. Could you point me to some article or Theorem that states why this is the desired result?

Comment: wait nevermind, it does make sense. Thank you :) this is still somewhat an algorithmic answer, I was hoping for a closed form. is there no such solution?

Comment: There is not really a general closed form unless you count $\frac{1}{k!} \, \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \prod\limits_{i=1}^m (1+n_i x) \Big|_{x=0}$ but taking the $k$th derivative of the product is not particularly easy unless you know something special about the values of $n_i$s such as them all being equal

Comment: If you want to learn more about generating functions, there is a good book to download at https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html